# Difference between energy and charge of an electron?

Tags: particle-physics

What is the difference between energy and charge for an outermost electron in a multi-electron atom (theoretically), which is less and which one is relatively more among them?

Answer (score 1):

Energy and charge have different units and can’t be compared. It’s like asking if your age is greater than your height. The numerical values depend on the units chosen for expressing age and height.

Comment: In addition, the charge of every electron in the universe is the same.